# C# Equivalent to this code

Tags: c#, javascript, photoshop

```
var xPos = new UnitValue( 0.5,'px') ;
var yPos = new UnitValue( 0.5,'px');
var pixPos = [ xPos, yPos ];
```

I have used this

```
Tuple<PsUnits, PsUnits> tuple = new Tuple<PsUnits,PsUnits>(xpos,ypos);
```

but not working for me. Any idea ??

I made a class

```
 public class pixpos
  {
    float XPOS;
    float YPOS;
    public float xpos
    {
        get
        {
            return this.XPOS;
        }
        set
        {
            this.XPOS = value;
        }
    }
    public float ypos
    {
        get { return this.YPOS; }
        set { this.YPOS = value; }
    }
}   
     pixpos obj = new pixpos();
                    obj.xpos = xPos;
                    obj.ypos = yPos;
```

its not working either i have to pass it as an argument to the `Colorsamples.Add();`

```
 Photoshop.Application appRef = default(Photoshop.Application);
var mySampler = appRef.ActiveDocument.ColorSamplers.Add(ps);
```

Comment: You must be sure to meet the signature, which photoshop ColorSamplers.Add() require. Simply transferring any object is perhaps a little bit to heavy, in order that Photoshop api should self extract the fitting data. If it expects an array as in the code above, then simply pass an array of floats with two entries.

Comment: "but not working for me" - how is it not working? Do you have a compiler error, or a runtime exception, or what? What does `ColorSamples.Add` expect as an argument?

Comment: yes it says the exception
Illegal Argument 1
Point Value (optionally in units) expected.

Comment: I cannot find any documentation about Photoshop.ColorSamplers.Add ()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a quick look at the interop and the *Add* method takes an object. As @icbytes implies, it takes an array so you could probably get away with an array of boxed objects. The interop uses `double` (not `float`) all over so `double` is probably the type you want to use.

For you own curiosity you should loop through the ColorSamplers collection and see what underlying types there are contained inside it. The collection stores objects that implement `ColorSampler` (which contains a `SolidColorClass` property) so if you know what objects implement this you can create those types to pass into the *Add* method.

Set the preference to pixels first to assume all values you provide are pixel-based.

```
Photoshop.Application appRef = default(Photoshop.Application);
appRef.Preferences.RulerUnits = PsUnits.psPixels;

foreach (ColorSampler sampler in appRef.ActiveDocument.ColorSamplers)
{
  // Check to see what underlying type a sampler is so you can try
  // and make instances of this to pass into the Add method.
  Console.WriteLine(sampler.GetType().FullName);
}

// Try add an object array of double values, based on the error message implied units could work.
// 'D' with convert the number literal to a 'double'.
appRef.ActiveDocument.ColorSamplers.Add(new object[] { 0.5D, 0.5D } );
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this page the add method requires an array. Passing the argument as anything else surely will cause a crash/exception:

http://cssdk.adobesites.com/sdk/1.0/docs/WebHelp/references/csawlib/com/adobe/photoshop/ColorSamplers.html

Comment: An array of what type should it be ??
int ?? float ?? i am stuck... :(

Comment: try float. As it seems, You  probably have to check, how UnitValue is typed internally.

Comment: Float is not working for me. I cannot find an example to use the ColorSamplers.add() method in C#

Comment: Then find out  how UnitValue is typed internally. 
You probably have to rebuild that kind of structure/object/whatever.