# Fast method for getting pixel color?

Tags: c#, photoshop, photoshop-script

I'm working on a Photoshop plugin using c# (with Adobe Photoshop Object Library). I'm trying to loop through all the pixels in my active document, but with the code I currently have it takes a very long time to even go through 1 row of pixels in a 256x256 file. I was wondering if there might be a better (faster) way than using ColorSampler for this? (c++ plugin?)

This is what I currently have:
(http://forums.adobe.com/thread/290211)
([C# Equivalent to this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177693/c-sharp-equivalent-to-this-code))

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ps.Application app = new ps.Application();
    app.Preferences.RulerUnits = ps.PsUnits.psPixels; 

    ps.Document activeDoc = app.ActiveDocument;

    double docWidth = activeDoc.Width;
    double docHeight = activeDoc.Height;
    double xPos = 0.0D;
    double yPos = 0.0D;             

    activeDoc.ColorSamplers.RemoveAll();
    var pixelLoc = new object[] { 0.0D, 0.0D };
    ps.ColorSampler myColorSampler = activeDoc.ColorSamplers.Add(pixelLoc);

    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    ps.SolidColor myColor;
    double red;
    double green;
    double blue;

    for (xPos = 0.0D; xPos <=docWidth - 1; xPos++)
    {
        myColor = myColorSampler.Color;
        red = myColor.RGB.Red;
        green = myColor.RGB.Green;
        blue = myColor.RGB.Blue;
        pixelLoc[0] = xPos;
        myColorSampler.Move(pixelLoc);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds); //11000 ms for 1 row of 256 pixels


    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Are you declaring variables in your for loop? That might be part of the problem...

Comment: Thanks! I've moved them out of the for loop and it did speed it up a bit (11000ms now - 13000ms before), I've edited my original post. But it's still very slow...

Comment: I would assume the loop itself is rather fast so there must be something inside that is causing it to be slow - maybe use the stop watch to profile each color call.  I also notice that you are calling myColor.RGB every time - does storing this in a variable once make any difference? You could also try using Parallel.For to run the loop in a threaded manner :)

Comment: Thanks! I've removed everything in the for loop except myColorSampler.Move(pixelLoc); and that still takes 11000ms. I guess that's just a really slow method? I also tried the threaded version and that sped it up a lot (6500ms now), but that's still very slow for just 1 row of 256 pixels isn't it? (I'd like to go through 4096x4096 bitmaps with this script)

Comment: May be a silly question, but is there a way to convert this "document" to a simple .net image/bitmap? Because if you can, then people may be able to help you better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not worked with this API before, but I found this website: [Adobe Photoshop CS5 Object Library](http://jongware.mit.edu/pscs5js_html/psjscs5/).

I did some looking and there is a SaveAs method that can be used on the Document object.  You can use this method to save the document as an image (let's say a BITMAP).

From there, you can use several sources online that show how to extract pixel information quickly from a BMP.

Here is one particular article: [Work with Bitmaps faster in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/240428/Work-with-bitmap-faster-with-Csharp)

I realize that I am not providing copy/pasteable code for you to use, but I hope this points you in the correct direction.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried this and I think this is probably the best solution for now. It only takes ~100 ms to save out a 4096x4096 bitmap file! I was just wondering if you might know if there is a way to maybe skip the writing to HDD part (can I save it to a MemoryStream e.g.). I now need to save it to the HDD first and then read it back in, this seems avoidable perhaps?

Comment: I'm glad this helped.  It seems that saving to disk is part of the SaveAs implementation, so there is probably no way around that unless you find an alternative to using SaveAs.  Ideally, the best way is to get an array of data from the active document in one call, but I just didn't see anything like that.